# access denied trying to get search Result Scopes in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search-results, search-scope

I have been trying to get to show all search scopes in sharepoint 2013. I can get remote Scopes, shared Scopes, and Local(web/site) Scopes, but I do not see the custom scopes that a user creates. I have been trying with use of SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy but I get an Access Denied error. Does anyone knows how to enumurate all Scopes, including custom scopes? Thanks

```
SPSite siteLowPrivileges = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
    delegate() {
    using(SPSite site = new SPSite(siteLowPrivileges.ID)) {
        // Get the service context for a selected site
        SPServiceContext spService = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
        // Access the service proxy instance of search application proxy.
        SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchServiceAppProxy = spService.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy))as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
        // Service Application Info object to retrieve the application id for the search service.
        SearchServiceApplicationInfo searchSerivceAppInfo = searchServiceAppProxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo();
        // Retrieve the search application instance for the specified id.
        SearchServiceApplication searchServiceApplication = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue < SearchServiceApplication > (searchSerivceAppInfo.SearchServiceApplicationId);

        // try to get 2013 result scopes
        SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy settingsProxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.GetValue < SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy > ();
        SearchServiceApplicationProxy farmProxy = settingsProxy.ApplicationProxies.GetValue < SearchServiceApplicationProxy > ("Search Service Application");
        SearchServiceApplicationInfo searchSerivceFarmAppInfo = farmProxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo();
        SearchServiceApplication searchServiceFarmApplication = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue < SearchServiceApplication > (searchSerivceFarmAppInfo.SearchServiceApplicationId);

        // get the current scopes defined in the search server
        Scopes scopes = new Scopes(searchServiceApplication);
        RemoteScopes remScopes = new RemoteScopes(spService);
        Scopes resultScopes = new Scopes(searchServiceFarmApplication);

        // show remote scopes
        retStr += "<br/><br/>Remote Scopes<br/>";
        foreach(Scope scope in remScopes.AllScopes) {
            retStr += showScope(scope);
        }

        // show shared scopes
        retStr += "<br/><br/>Shared Scopes<br/>";
        foreach(Scope scope in scopes.GetSharedScopes()) {
            retStr += showScope(scope);
        }

        // show web scopes
        retStr += "<br/><br/>Web Scopes<br/>";
        foreach(Scope scope in scopes.GetScopesForSite(site.PrimaryUri)) {
            retStr += showScope(scope);
        }

        // show result scopes
        retStr += "<br/><br/>Result Scopes<br/>";
        try {
            // ERROR HERE when accessing .AllScopes
            foreach(Scope scope in resultScopes.AllScopes) {
                retStr += showScope(scope);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
            retStr += "<br/><b> error: " + ex.Message + "</b><br/>";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This way it works. Result scopes are not really scopes. There must be a better way than casting with Federation Manager, but anyway it works.

```
public string showAllScopes() {      
    string retStr = "<b>Demo reuslts</b><br/>";      
    SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);

    // Get the service context for a selected site
    SPServiceContext spService = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    // Access the service proxy instance of search application proxy. 
    SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchServiceAppProxy = spService.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
    // Service Application Info object to retrieve the application id for the search service.
    SearchServiceApplicationInfo searchSerivceAppInfo = searchServiceAppProxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo();
    // Retrieve the search application instance for the specified id.
    SearchServiceApplication searchServiceApplication = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(searchSerivceAppInfo.SearchServiceApplicationId);
    // get the current scopes defined in the search server
    Scopes scopes = new Scopes(searchServiceApplication);
    RemoteScopes remScopes = new RemoteScopes(spService);   

    // get 2013 result scopes
    SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy settingsProxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.GetValue<SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy>();
    SearchServiceApplicationProxy farmProxy = settingsProxy.ApplicationProxies.GetValue<SearchServiceApplicationProxy>("Search Service Application");
    FederationManager instance = new FederationManager(farmProxy);
    SearchObjectFilter filter = new SearchObjectFilter(SearchObjectLevel.SPWeb);
    bool includeInactive = false;
    IEnumerable<Source> returnValue = default(IEnumerable<Source>);
    returnValue = instance.ListSources(filter, includeInactive);    

    // remote scopes            
    retStr += "<br/><br/>Remote Scopes<br/>";
    foreach (Scope scope in remScopes.AllScopes)
    {
        retStr += showScope(scope);
    }

    // shared scopes           
    retStr += "<br/><br/>Shared Scopes<br/>";
    foreach (Scope scope in scopes.GetSharedScopes())
    {
        retStr += showScope(scope);
    }

    // web scopes
    retStr += "<br/><br/>Web Scopes<br/>";
    foreach (Scope scope in scopes.GetScopesForSite(site.PrimaryUri))
    {
        retStr += showScope(scope);
    }

    // result Sources
    retStr += "<br/><br/>Result Scopes<br/>";                         
    foreach (Source scope in returnValue)
    {
        retStr += showScope(scope);
    }

    return retStr;}
```

and the helper method

```
private string showScope(dynamic scope) {
    string retStr = "";          
    retStr += "<br/>" + " ScopeName: " + scope.Name +
                    " / description: " + scope.Description;

    return retStr;
}
```

ok, to be 100%, here are the usings. Maybe some are not really needed

using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Serialization;